# Making a program that sends an email which hyperlinks text in django

Tags: python, html, django

```
confirm_links = 'To confirm this order http://mywebsite.com '
deny_links = '\nTo deny this order http://mywebsite.com 

email=EmailMessage('title_text',  confirm_links+deny_links, to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
email.send()
signals.post_save.connect(send_email_on_new_order, sender= PurchaseOrder, dispatch_uid = 'send_email_on_new_order')
```

My program sends a link to the user where they can click those two links to either confirm or deny their order. I would like to make it to where, they don't see the line http://mywebsite.com  and instead just see "order" hyperlinked which goes to http://mywebsite.com

Comment: do you not know how to do a link in html? ...

Comment: I tried <a href =http://mywebsite.com /a> but it was not working in gmail. Somehow HTML needs to be enabled, I guess. I'm still very new to HTML. I apologize.

Comment: A correction link tag is `<a href="http://mywebsite.com">blabla</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types):

> By default, the MIME type of the body parameter in an EmailMessage is
>   "text/plain"

Put your links in `<a>` tags and set `email.content_subtype = "html"`:

```
confirm_links = 'To confirm this <a href="http://mywebsite.com">order</a>'
deny_links = '\nTo deny this <a href="http://mywebsite.com">order</a>'
email=EmailMessage('title_text',  confirm_links+deny_links, to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
email.content_subtype = "html"
email.send()
```

Though, it's a good practice to send both text and HTML versions of a message. Consider using `EmailMultiAlternatives` for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a classic link, you just have to use the HTML `<a>` tag. Also if you want to point to a particular URL, you can use the `reverse()` function (see the [documentation about URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls))

Also set `email.content_subtype = "html"`